# Random background-image url inside the .css file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I ran across this this CSS file on a videogame website. Check out the URL and wait about five minutes and refresh and the background image URL will be changed. This all happens inside the css file.

Any ideas how this is done? I've tried an extensive Google and couldn't find a solution.

[Link to CSS file on Rockstar.com](http://www.rockstargames.com/downloads/randomBackground/index.css)

Comment: check out this http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: You can do this using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use curl to retrieve it, `-v` option to see the headers.

```
curl -v http://www.rockstargames.com/downloads/randomBackground/index.css
```

It has a very short shelf life, does not cache for very long.

The server rewrites this file, or generates it dynamically, with a different image target.  When you refresh, you get the rewritten `index.css.`

To elaborate, in response to the comment …

The randomBackground/index.css file is just a file on the file system of the server, just like a file in a directory on your computer.  The http:// … address identifies the file to the server, which sends it to you.

Now, some process on the server-- a program --can have a list of background images, or look at a directory full of background images, and choose one at random or work sequentially through them.  It picks an image, then rewrites the randomBackground/index.css file using the new image name.  It completely replaces the old file content with new file content.

Each time you retrieve the file you can potentially get a completely new version with new content.

It is also possible for the web server to map that address to a process, not a file, a program that sends the content with the random background image name.  That is how I would do it; however, usually, if that is the case, the address would not look like a file name.

Comment: How would they have the file renamed and preloaded with the a new image target? Would someone be uploading a batch of files every for the background only?